# An extension for Apple's Look Up

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I am learning French. Every time I use the Force Click on my Mac on a word I don't know, I get a dictionary entry and a translation to English.

But when I want to translate a whole sentence, I have to open Google Translate to do so. (1. Open Google Translate. 2. Copy sentence 3. Paste Sentence) It is pretty annoying to do that 20-30 times a day.

So is there a way to expand the capabilities of Force Click in Safari (or in the best case, in every application which allows "Look Up")?

Let me worry about how I can translate the sentences.

I am open for any kind of creative solution.

[Here is the standard pop-up when I force touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d76Kz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a documented way to achieve this on a force click, but you may want to look at *Services*.

Basically, you can create an application that provides a service, select some text, and then choose your application's Service menu item from the Services submenu in your *Application Name* menu (the one in bold where "Hide" etc. are).

The service will then receive a copy of the selection (in an `NSPasteboard`) and can do whatever it wants with that, or even change it.